# onTouch event in android

Tags: android

i have a AnalogClock in layout. if i touch the AnalogClock the next activity will be come.
how to write onTouch event for AnalogClock. i use this following code:

AnalogClock time;

```
time =(AnalogClock)findViewbyId(R.id.Widget44);
```

time.(i do not get any function list) please correct me.

Comment: sorry it is AnalogClock. i edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html), `AnalogClock` inherits from `View` and therefore you can use the methods `setOnClickListener(...)` or `setOnTouchListener(...)` which should satisfy your needs.

Comment: i imported the classes and still not get setOnTouchListener. i am new to android. i write the code in OnCreate method. please correct me.

Comment: Then this seems to be a problem concerning your IDE, since the functions definitely exist! What IDE are you using?

Comment: eclipse galileo. and project target is google api platform is 3.0
eclipse detail(installed software)
  Android DDMS 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group
  Android Development Tools 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
  Eclipse SDK 3.5.2.M20100211-1343 org.eclipse.sdk.ide

Comment: Mh, is there anything which prevents you from upgrading to the latest Eclipse version?

Comment: no, last time i installed package from available software from android sdk.

Comment: Mh I don't fully understand your answer... go directly to [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/), download the latest version and then follow the procedure to install the Android SDK again?